# Start the SpringBoot project as a Jar package

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jar

My SpringBoot project can be started normally in the development tool in the form of source code, but when I package it as a jar and upload it to Linux to start, it prompts me this error, please give me some advice on how to troubleshoot the problem.....(The erased part is the startup class of my project)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfCa5.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide the build description file? maybe pom.xml if you're using Maven. or build.gradle if you're using gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stacktrace it seems that

[image]

Can you check at `CometClientRegistrar.java` 209 line? I think when you run from your ide, you are adding few settings like environment variables, options which you are missing when you run jar manually with `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: We use an independent configuration center to manage all the configuration of the project, so we use plugins to exclude all configuration files when packaging, but there is a properties configuration file in an external dependency that is ignored and a configuration item cannot be loaded

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to help me check this issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how are you creating a jar of spring boot. If you may share steps to create a jar. Is it via dev tool (intellij/STS/eclipse) or a parameter in application.properties/yml file?

Comment: Made this jar using Maven packaging plugin in IDEA

Comment: Hope its resolved